# Is it incorrect to substitute the expression of a function by the expression of it's asymptote in a limit to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let's consider a function $f(x)$ that has a slant asymptote in $+\infty$ of equation $y = m_1x + b_1$.
Let's consider another function $g(x)$ that also as a slant asymptote in $+\infty$ of equation $y = m_2x + b_2$.

When calculating the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$, is it correct to substitute the expressions of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by the respective asymptotes and evaluate the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{m_1x + b_1}{m_2x + b_2}}$?

Comment: Have you tried to find an $\epsilon, \delta$ argument to resolve this question?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $m_1x+b_1$ is an slant asymptote of $f(x)$ means $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{m_1x+b_1} = 1$.

So $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{m_1x+b_1}\cdot \frac{m_1x+b_1}{g(x)} = 1\cdot \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{m_1x+b_1}{g(x)}$$

Do the same for $g(x)$